# Check that current file is doc, docx, xls, xlsx or pdf format

Tags: c++, pdf, docx

How i can check that current file is doc, docx, xls, xlsx or pdf format? What's a c++ library i can use for this goal in my C++ application?

Comment: From a filename or from contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to understand file's type based on its contents, you can check the file's **[binary signature](http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html)**.

---

If you want just to check the extension, you have 2 nice options:

1. Use [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) functions [`find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/), [`find_first_of`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_of/), [`find_last_of`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_last_of/) and [`substr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) to write your own logic that analyzes the file name.
2. Use [boost filesystem library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/index.htm)'s function [`extension`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#path-extension).

Comment: I mustn't check extension or analyzes the file name.

Comment: For instance, "file.docx" isn't docs file, but have "docx" extension

Comment: Then you'll need to look at the magic number in the file, per the first part of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, the `file` command can be used to determine the file type. You'd use `popen()` to call the `file` command and capture its output.